# how to import css file in nativescript-vue project?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

i'm stuck with this...

i don't know to import my scss file in my nativescript-vue project

i tried with

```
require('style.scss')
```

with nativescript-dev-sass

i copy paste ns doc
https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling

```
import { Application } from "@nativescript/core";
Application.setCssFileName("style.css");

Application.run({ moduleName: "main-page" });
```

but it didn't work neither